# Error: expected a property attribute before 'atomic'

Tags: ios, ipad

I get the following exception on this line:

```
@property (atomic ,retain) NSString *title;

error: expected a property attribute before 'atomic'
```

What does that mean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no keyword atomic to use in a declared property. A property declared is by default behaving "atomic" so you don't have to set it explicitely. You just change the default behaviour by adding nonatomic. As this is a compile time directive it is not needed to change this value during runtime, making "atomic" needless.

Quoting Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language / Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html)

> Atomicity
>
> You can use this attribute to specify
>   that accessor methods are not atomic.
>   (There is no keyword to denote
>   atomic.)
>
> nonatomic Specifies that accessors are
>   nonatomic. By default, accessors are
>   atomic. Properties are atomic by
>   default so that synthesized accessors
>   provide robust access to properties in
>   a multithreaded environment—that is,
>   the value returned from the getter or
>   set via the setter is always fully
>   retrieved or set regardless of what
>   other threads are executing
>   concurrently. For more details, see
>   “Performance and Threading.”